# Installing a package in Conda environment, but only works in Python not iPython?

Tags: python, docker, path, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using an Ubuntu docker image. I've installed Anaconda on it with no issues. I'm not trying to install tensorflow, using the directions on the tensorflow website:

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
source activate tensorflow
<tensorflow> conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

It installs with no errors. However, when I import in `iPython`, it tells me there is no module `tensorflow`. But if I import when in `Python`, it works fine.

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install IPython in the conda environment

```
source activate tensorflow
conda install ipython
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing. We are installing tensorflow in different conda environment. So It may not consist of all the packages. I needed to install jupyter notebook separately in order to work.